# Actionbarsherlock searchview with suggestions

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, searchview

My development environment is Eclipse and i'm using the Actionbarsherlock.
I want that once I start to write text inside the actionbarsherlock SearchView it will drop down a list of suggestions.
Like this:

[image]

I'm really new to using the ActionbarSherlock library in android so please can you give me an example of how to make this drop down list once you start searching in side the SearchView.

Mainly I am reading the Phone Contacts Content Provider and I would like to show their name + phonenumber + photo if the string you write inside the searchview mathces a substring or the whole string of the contact name. Basically I would like that the SearchView would let you search contacts by their names and show a list of them with their names + phone + photo.

Comment: Already worked through the official guide? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-recent-query-suggestions.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html It's pretty much the same.

Answer (score 3):

With the current ActionBarSherlock library (release 4.2) that's not possible. Though there is a fix in the dev tree of ActionBarSherlock, that allows you to do that.

Just open the [dev tree branch on the ActionBarSherlock project page](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/dev) and download the repository as a zip file. Don't worry, the next release of ActionBarSherlock - containing this fix - is probably not too far away. For now the dev tree should suffice.

Follow the [official guidelines about using the SearchView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) or simply hop over to my [blog post about ActionViews](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-actionviews-to-your-actionbar/) - where I also show how to make use of it. I use ActionBarSherlock there myself.

Comment: Well I tried your suggestion..seems the dev tree doesn't contain everything which is in the master...to many errors due to the switch concerning styles/themes etc ..going to wait for a new master.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its the same?
Because i saw in forums that people says the actionbarsherlock is different from the android offical...